# How do I set up Windows 11 on a new desktop system using a bluetooth keyboard?

Tags: windows, keyboard, bluetooth, windows-11, computer-building

I am building a new desktop PC with Windows 11, and my intention is to use a [Microsoft Bluetooth Keyboard](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-microsoft-bluetooth-keyboard-87947e66-e023-38a8-aa9a-7ca238ef5d67#WindowsVersion=Windows_11) with it, through a Bluetooth USB dongle.  I *will* have a wired mouse available since I have a spare.

Is there any way to get the setup started using the Bluetooth keyboard?  Not only will Windows 11 need driver support for the dongle out of the box, but I'll need to pair the keyboard device.  Does Windows 11 setup have the capability to do both these things?  (If I have to, I'll borrow a wired keyboard to get the setup done.)

I have not started anything yet— I just want to make sure I have a wired keyboard handy if it will be necessary.

(It might turn out to be a moot point if I need to get to BIOS setup on the motherboard to boot from the USB drive containing Windows setup.  *Can* you get to BIOS during power-on on a system with only a Bluetooth keyboard?)

Comment: You will need a USB keyboard to get started with and get into BIOS.  Bluetooth is unlikely to allow what you want (not drivers at the time).

Comment: "Is there any way to get the setup started using the Bluetooth keyboard?" - You might be able to achieve this by creating your own WinPE environment, however, the installation environment I am almost certain will NOT support BT.  Which is fine, since you can create and apple .wim images to partitions using a script.

Comment: Can you get to BIOS during power-on on a system with only a Bluetooth keyboard?)     ...... You need a USB keyboard to get into BIOS.  On my systems at least.

Comment: Use the wired mouse. I didn't test on Windows 11, but during the installation you might see an icon in the lower left of the screen to launch the on-screen keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up windows 11 without a keyboard. After initial setup starts, select the on-screen keyboard from the accessibility options. That option is not selectable for all dialog boxes, so get the keyboard up first. Later you can use the mouse to key in a Wifi password, a name for the system, and user credentials.

I used a logitech bluetooth mouse for this setup. I inserted the logitech universal receiver, and put my mouse in pairing mode, before pressing the power button on the system.  Once I got past initial setup, Logitech auto-installed "logi options" which I could use to pair my BT keyboard with the system.